# How does gradle handle settings.gradle files in subdirectories?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a android gradle project with the following directory structure:

```
\ MyProject
  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle
  \ app
    - build.gradle
  \ Libs
    \ Lib1
      - build.gradle
      - settings.gradle
```

`MyProject/settings.gradle` looks like this:

```
include ':app'
include ':Lib1'
project(':Lib1').projectDir = new File('Libs/Lib1')
```

The module `app` depends on the module `Lib1` like so (`MyProject/app/build.gradle`)

```
// Rest of file elided
dependencies {
    // Other dependencies elided
    compile project(':Lib1')
}
```

Here's the issue: when I force-sync in Android Studio, the sync fails with an error:

```
Unable to find module with Gradle path ':Lib1'
```

This messes up some code highlighting in `app` (classes in `Lib1` are not recognized).

But when I rename `MyProject/Libs/Lib1/settings.gradle` to something else, the sync works properly.

So I have two questions:

1. Is this an issue with Gradle or with Android Studio?
2. Is there a way to tell Gradle to ignore `settings.gradle` files in subdirectories? That does seem to be the most direct way of fixing this issue.

Comment: I was under the impression that you only want one `settings.gradle`, in the overall project root. Why do you have the ones in `app/` and `Libs/lib1/`?

Comment: I understand that. The real name of `Libs/Lib1` is a forked version of [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), which I've imported by cloning the git repo into `MyProject`. (I didn't add it myself, if that's what you're asking.) Also, I don't have one in `app`, that was a typo.